# Pandas Merge two tables with the second tables' one column transposed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Table 1**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'df1_id':['1','2','3'],'col1':["a","b","c"],'col2':["d","e","f"]})
```

[image]

---

**Table 2**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'df1_id':['1','2','1','1'],'date':['01-05-2021','03-05-2021','05-05-2021','03-05-2021'],'data':[12,13,16,9],'test':['g','h','j','i'],'test2':['k','l','m','n']})
```

[image]

---

**Result Table**

[image]

---

**Brief Explanation on how the Result table needs to be created:**

1. I have two data frames and I want to merge them based on a `df_id`. But the `date` column from second table should be transposed into the resultant table.
2. The date columns for the result table will be a range between the min date and max date from the second table
3. The column values for the dates in the result table will be from the `data` column of the second table.
4. Also the `test` column from the second table will only take its value of the latest date for the result table

I hope this is clear. Any suggestion or help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using pivot on the second table and then trying to merge the pivoted second table `df1` but its not working. I do not know how to get only one row for the latest value of test.

Note: I am trying to solve this problem using vectorization and do not want to serially parse through each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for the question:

1. I first sort `df2` based of `df1_id` and `date` to ensure that table entries are in order.
2. Then I drop duplicates based on `df_id` and select the last row to ensure I have the latest values for `test` and `test2`
3. Then I pivot `df2` to get the corresponding `date` as column and `data` as its value
4. Then I merge the table with `df2_pivoted` to combine the latest values of `test` and `test2`
5. Then I merge with `df1` to get the resultant table

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'df1_id':['1','2','3'],'col1':["a","b","c"],'col2':["d","e","f"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'df1_id':['1','2','1','1'],'date':['01-05-2021','03-05-2021','05-05-2021','03-05-2021'],'data':[12,13,16,9],'test':['g','h','j','i'],'test2':['k','l','m','n']})


df2=df2.sort_values(by=['df1_id','date'])
df2_latest_vals = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['df1_id'],keep='last')

df2_pivoted = df2.pivot_table(index=['df1_id'],columns=['date'],values=['data'])
df2_pivoted = df2_pivoted.droplevel(0,axis=1).reset_index()
df2_pivoted = pd.merge(df2_pivoted,df2_latest_vals,on='df1_id')
df2_pivoted = df2_pivoted.drop(columns=['date','data'])

result = pd.merge(df1,df2_pivoted,on='df1_id',how='left')
result
```

[image]

**Note: I have not been able to figure out how to get the entire date range between 01-05-2021 and 05-05-2021 and show the empty values as NaN. If anyone can help please edit the answer**

Answer (score 0):

You need to `pivot` your `df2` into two separate table as we need `data` and `test` values and then merge both resulting pivot table with `df1`

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'df1_id':['1','2','3'],'col1':["a","b","c"],'col2':["d","e","f"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'df1_id':['1','2','1','1'],'date':['01-05-2021','03-05-2021','03-05-2021','05-05-2021'],'data':[12,13,9,16],'test':['g','h','i','j']})

test_piv = df2.pivot(index=['df1_id'],columns=['date'],values=['test'])
data_piv = df2.pivot(index=['df1_id'],columns=['date'],values=['data'])

max_test = test_piv['test'].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1].rename('test')
final = df1.merge(data_piv['data'],left_on=df1.df1_id, right_index=True, how='left')
final = final.merge(max_test,left_on=df1.df1_id, right_index=True, how='left')
```

and hence your resulting `final` dataframe as below

```
|    |   df1_id | col1   | col2   |   01-05-2021 |   03-05-2021 |   05-05-2021 | test   |
|---:|---------:|:-------|:-------|-------------:|-------------:|-------------:|:-------|
|  0 |        1 | a      | d      |           12 |            9 |           16 | j      |
|  1 |        2 | b      | e      |          nan |           13 |          nan | h      |
|  2 |        3 | c      | f      |          nan |          nan |          nan | nan    |
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to get the dates between 01-05-2921, 05-05-2021 and show the values as NaN.

Comment: Also if you have multiple columns in table2 - ```test1```,```test2```,```test3```..... It would get very cumbersome do do pivots for each column. I have edited the question to incorporate this complexity

Comment: I have posted an answer myself. I have still not able to figure out how to get the entire date range. Lets discuss if yours or my answer is better suited to the question. Then I will mark that one as the answer